# How to export a .fbx file with vertex colors for substance painter

Tags: texture-baking, .fbx, vertex-colors

I am trying to use vertex colors in order to utilize substance painter's ID mask baking functionality.  Is there any way to export vertex colors in the high-poly .fbx file to generate the ID map?  I have painted the vertex colors but there has been no change upon rebaking in SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem.  I had failed to select vertex colors as the ID map color source in Substance Painter.